# how do I run a function in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I'm programming a project, and i need a way to run a function every time i access django admin.

this function change some things in the DB, and if you know an easy way for it, i'll be happy. a thing like a function that run every time the database changes.

thanks

Comment: Well....first you'll have to set a model in the models.py then you can create a view which could kinda do that?? Idk what you want to do tho.

Comment: i've already created a model, so how can i do this?

Comment: Could you share all your code?

Comment: thanks, i managed a solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way, was create a view and access with ajax, extending the admin's base.html and adding my js.

view:

```
def updateDataBase(request):
    # your function
    return HttpResponse('')
```

And with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/my-view-url/',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success')
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        console.log('Error')
    }
});
```